# accessing parsed JSON on the iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, json, twitter, flickr

I've been following the great tutorial about ([iPhone, json and Flickr API](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/networking/iphone-json-flickr-tutorial-part-1.html) and I did manage to access the parsed json info just fine.

Now I'm trying to do the same thing with the Twitter API, and I am able to get the json info and parse it, but I can't seem to access it like in Flickr.

I noticed that the json info that is retrieved from Twitter is a little different from Flickr.

The Flickr json info starts straight with a curly braces (**{**), while the Twitter json info starts with a square bracket and then a curly braces (**[{**).
I understand that it means it's an array inside the json info, but I don't know how to access it.

In the Flickr example, I access the objects like so (the second line takes the number of pages Flickr has reported):

```
NSDictionary *results = [jsonString JSONValue];
pagesString = [[results objectForKey:@"photos"] objectForKey:@"pages"];
```

but I can't seem to access the Twitter response in the same way...

Does anyone know of a solution?

(here's an example of the Twitter JSON response: api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.json )

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
NSArray *results = [jsonString JSONValue];
NSDictionary *first = [results objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"screen name = %@", [first objectForKey:@"screen_name"]);
```

etc?

Comment: That did the trick.
Thank you very much, Paul!

(i tried to vote your answer up, but I need more reputation)

Comment: I have json file its starting is not '{' or '['  it start with'jsont' .  How can I use this json format. http://ntp-a1.nict.go.jp/cgi-bin/jsont?1232963971.248                                                                  jsont({
  "id": "ntp-a1.nict.go.jp",
  "it": 1232963971.248,
  "st": 1344241456.129,
  "leap": 34,
  "next": 1341100800,
  "step": 1
})

Comment: The string prefix makes it bad JSON.  I suggest reading it in as a string, stripping off the prefix, and then proceeding as above.